# Saving SecKeyRef device generated public/private key pair on disk

Tags: iphone, ios, security, cryptography

I've generated an RSA symmetric key pair on a device using `SecKeyGeneratePair()` on a device. I have `SecKeyRef` struct pointers for each key. So, how do I save a `SecKeyRef` to disk? Or even transmit it (I also imagine there are issues with correct encoding too)? Apple's 'Certificate, Key, and Trust Services' Guide notes

> You can send your public key to anyone, who can then use it to encrypt data.

I'd like to save the private key especially; so I can use it on deployed devices to decrypt data encrypted with the public key.

P.S. I don't mind if the resulting data for each key is DER-encoded ASN.1 or base-64; I just need to figure out how to pull the key out of a `SecKeyRef`. I'm also well-aware of the non-existence of OS X's `SecKeychainItemExport()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, found the answer myself; you can get the bytes for a public key using `SecItemCopyMatching()`.

```
- (NSData *)getPublicKeyBits {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData * publicKeyBits = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set the public key query dictionary.
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnData];

    // Get the key bits.
    sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyBits);

    if (sanityCheck != noErr)
    {
        publicKeyBits = nil;
    }

    [queryPublicKey release];

    return publicKeyBits;
}
```

The above is from Apple's CryptoExercise. Not sure if it works for private keys though.

Comment: Nope. I filled a bug report but it was never acknowledged.

Comment: In your code above, what is `publicTag`? When I used my `SecKeyRef` in place of `publicTag`, I received "Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'SecKey')" `SecKeyRef` is a RSA public key in an opaque (Apple) format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the latest crypto API of iOS, You can save the key as NSData and retrieve the key from NSData

```
SecKeyRef key = <# a key #>;
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
NSData* keyData = (NSData*)CFBridgingRelease(  // ARC takes ownership
                       SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(key, &error)
                   );
if (!keyData) {
    NSError *err = CFBridgingRelease(error);  // ARC takes ownership
    // Handle the error. . .
}
```

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_as_data?language=objc

Comment: This solution is only for iOS10+

Answer (score 0):

See the [Encrypting and Decrypting Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW9) section of the Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Programming Guide, which has code samples to generate, save, and use public/private key pairs.