# iOS SecKeyRef to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, rsa

I have two keys, public and private, that are both stored in SecKeyRef-variables. For simplicity's sake, let's start with the public one. What I wanna do is export it to an NSData object. For that, there is an almost famous code snippet provide by Apple, which is here:

```
- (NSData *)getPublicKeyBits {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData * publicKeyBits = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set the public key query dictionary.
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnData];

    // Get the key bits.
    sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyBits);

    if (sanityCheck != noErr)
    {
        publicKeyBits = nil;
    }

    [queryPublicKey release];

    return publicKeyBits;
}
```

I have Xcode 4.6.2, however, and the code appears erroneous ("__bridge" is added before each conversion to id). The new version looks like this:

```
- (NSData *)getPublicKeyBitsFromKey:(SecKeyRef)givenKey {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData * publicKeyBits = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set the public key query dictionary.
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];

    // Get the key bits.
    sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyBits);

    if (sanityCheck != noErr)
    {
        publicKeyBits = nil;
    }

    return publicKeyBits;
}
```

There are still two errors, though:

- use of undeclared identifier 'publicTag'
- Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'CFTypeRef *' (aka 'const void **') is disallowed with ARC

Now, I hope that after your help, the first issue will no longer be a problem, for I do not want to build a query or whatnot to extract the key from the keychain. **I have it in a variable and I wish to extract it from there.** The variable's name is `givenPublicKey`, and that's the key I wish to convert to NSData.

So, how would I go about doing this and solving this ARC-issue?

Follow-up: How can I export a *private* key to NSData, since I've read several time that the function I'm trying to work with only works for public keys.

Comment: Could you reference the code snippet to Apple's docs/site?

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008019-Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m-DontLinkElementID_17

Comment: You can export both public and private keys to NSData: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_as_data?language=objc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- use of undeclared identifier 'publicTag'

The `publicTag` is just some unique identifier added to the Keychain items. In the CryptoExercise sample project it is defined as

```
#define kPublicKeyTag "com.apple.sample.publickey"
static const uint8_t publicKeyIdentifier[] = kPublicKeyTag;
NSData *publicTag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier length:sizeof(publicKeyIdentifier)];
```

- Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'CFTypeRef ' (aka 'const void *') is disallowed with ARC

This can be solved by using a temporary `CFTypeRef` variable:

```
CFTypeRef result;
sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, &result);
if (sanityCheck == errSecSuccess) {
    publicKeyBits = CFBridgingRelease(result);
}
```

- I do not want to build a query or whatnot to extract the key from the keychain. I have it in a variable and I wish to extract it from there ...

As far as I know, you have to store the SecKeyRef to the Keychain temporarily. `SecItemAdd` 
has the option to return the added item as data. From the documentation:

> To obtain the data of the added item as an object of type `CFDataRef`,
>   specify the return type key `kSecReturnData` with a value of
>   `kCFBooleanTrue`.

Putting all that together, the following code should do what you want:

```
- (NSData *)getPublicKeyBitsFromKey:(SecKeyRef)givenKey {

    static const uint8_t publicKeyIdentifier[] = "com.your.company.publickey";
    NSData *publicTag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier length:sizeof(publicKeyIdentifier)];

    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData * publicKeyBits = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];

    // Temporarily add key to the Keychain, return as data:
    NSMutableDictionary * attributes = [queryPublicKey mutableCopy];
    [attributes setObject:(__bridge id)givenKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueRef];
    [attributes setObject:@YES forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
    CFTypeRef result;
    sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributes, &result);
    if (sanityCheck == errSecSuccess) {
        publicKeyBits = CFBridgingRelease(result);

        // Remove from Keychain again:
        (void)SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) queryPublicKey);
    }

    return publicKeyBits;
}
```

I hope that this works, I cannot test it at the moment.

- Follow-up: How can I export a private key to NSData, since I've read several time that the function I'm trying to work with only works for public keys.

I don't know.

Comment: can we use it for mac ? returns error - invalid key 
when used

Comment: I get back a weird size for the key data. In my case I imported an identity with a 2048bit key (256 bytes), However the NSData returned from this function has a size of 270 bytes.

Comment: Oddly, when I run this code as part of an iOS app it works fine.  However, when using it as part of an OS X application the OSStatus result is 'An invalid key was encountered'.