# iOS - RSA Public Key SecKeyRef to NSData

Tags: ios, cryptography, keychain

I have a keypair stored in an iOS keychain.  I'm able to get `SecKeyRef` objects for both the public and private keys with no problem.  What I need, however, is to convert `SecKeyRef` for the public key to an `NSData` object.  I've tried the code below that I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748993/ios-seckeyref-to-nsdata)...

```
- (NSData *)getPublicKeyBitsFromKey:(SecKeyRef)givenKey {

    static const uint8_t publicKeyIdentifier[] = "com.your.company.publickey";
    NSData *publicTag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier length:sizeof(publicKeyIdentifier)];

    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData * publicKeyBits = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];

    // Temporarily add key to the Keychain, return as data:
    NSMutableDictionary * attributes = [queryPublicKey mutableCopy];
    [attributes setObject:(__bridge id)givenKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueRef];
    [attributes setObject:@YES forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
    CFTypeRef result;
    sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributes, &result);
    if (sanityCheck == errSecSuccess) {
        publicKeyBits = CFBridgingRelease(result);

        // Remove from Keychain again:
        (void)SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) queryPublicKey);
    }

    return publicKeyBits;
}
```

...however, when I run it, I get an OSStatus value of -50, which indicates a bad parameter somewhere.  However, I can't find what could be the issue.  Am I missing something in my code?  Or is there a better way to convert a `SecKeyRef` to an `NSData` object?  Any help you can provide is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Did you maybe find the answer, I am struggling with the same thing, and for me it works on iOS but not on OSX