# How to convert RSA pem file to XML in swift? or How to get RSA XML in swift?

Tags: swift, rsa, pem

I have a project on who want to generate a public and private key with RSA and I use [SwiftyRSA](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA), but it just can export PEM, base64 and data format. Now how can I convert those formate to XML?

```
   do {
        let keyPair = try SwiftyRSA.generateRSAKeyPair(sizeInBits: 2048)
        let privateKey = keyPair.privateKey
        let publicKey = keyPair.publicKey

        print("pemString:==============\npr-> \(try! privateKey.pemString())")
        print("base64String:==============\npr-> \(try! privateKey.base64String())")
        print("data:==============\npr-> \(try! privateKey.data())")

    } catch {
        print("error -> No key generated")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML file is simply a text with some structure. In your case it's:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>
        ...
    </Modulus>
    <Exponent>
        ...
    </Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

So you can simply extract modulus and exponent from string returned by `pemString()` and put it in your XML template.

[Can I get the modulus or exponent from a SecKeyRef object in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408825/can-i-get-the-modulus-or-exponent-from-a-seckeyref-object-in-swift)